# Postgresql same date record insert

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger, postgresql-9.5

I am using a Postgresql 9.5 database. A third party software application is also using this database. I have a `Features` table.  I created an `Events` table to record `Features` events.

```
Features
------------
id     name   lon   lat
1        x     0    10
2        y     15   20
```

When I create a record in the `Features` table, my trigger inserts a record into the `Events` table.

```
Events
id    name      date                    feature_id
1     insert    09.04.2018 14:22:23.065125        1
```

When I update Features `name`, `lon` and `lat` and save it, the software execution results in 3 update records at same time.

```
Events
id    name      date                          feature_id
1     insert    09.04.2018 14:22:23.065125        1
2     update    09.04.2018 18:15:41.099689        1
3     update    09.04.2018 18:15:41.099689        1
4     update    09.04.2018 18:15:41.099689        1
```

But this is 3 update is same values.

How can I restrict this in my trigger?

My trigger function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION event_fn() AS $BODY$ BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO events (event_name, event_date, feature_id) VALUES ('insert', now(), NEW.id);
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        INSERT INTO events (event_name, event_date, feature_id) VALUES ('update', now(), NEW.id);
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        INSERT INTO events (event_name, event_date, feature_id) VALUES ('delete', now(), OLD.id);
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF; 
END;
```

Comment: could you also share the trigger/function code?

Comment: @JimJones updated the post

Comment: *"And When I update Feature name, lon and lat and save it, the software executes 3 update record in same time."* Are you running three update statements, one each for `name`, `lon`, and `lat`?

Comment: @barteloma : could it be that you're firing this `update` 3 times? I see no reason for it to store the same record 3 times.

Comment: The update query is executing by 3rd party software. I can not see source code of it.

Comment: Turn on full statement logging in PG to see what the update statement is.

Comment: Try what @eurotrash just recommended. I really think this 3rd party software is performing the update 3 times.

Comment: if it execute update 3 times, why dates are same? It should be differend milliseconds.

Comment: @barteloma - the three updates are executed in a single transaction, so the time is the same.

Comment: @klin it make sense executing in single transaction. Is there any solution in this stuation?

Comment: @barteloma - well, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to opt out of the software that performs several updates instead of actually a single one. However, if you can not do this, you can add a trigger for the `events` table, e.g.:

```
create or replace function before_insert_on_events()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if exists (
        select 1
        from events e
        where e.name = new.name
        and e.date = new.date
        and e.feature_id = new.feature_id)
    then new = null;
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger before_insert_on_events
before insert on events
for each row
execute procedure before_insert_on_events();
```